# Jinja2 If ignores boolean value

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I have a Jinja2 template where a variable that resolves as a boolean False is being ignored in an `{% if %}` statement.

The relevant chunk of the template looks like

```
{% if user.can_manage_techniques %}j
{% block submenu_items %}
<li class="pure-menu-item"><a href={{ url_for('new_technique') }} class="pure-menu-link">New Technique</a></li>
{% endblock %}
{% endif %}
```

The user is set in render template as

```py
    return render_template('technique_list.j2',
                            techniques=Technique.find_all(),
                            **state())
```

with the state being a function that returns a dict[string, object].

The user that is passed to it is set in the `__init__` of the object as a variable - so:

```py
    def __init__(self):
        self.can_manage_techniques = False
```

**Even when the `can_manage_techniques` is false, the list item still renders**. How do I make the `{% if %}` realise that it is false and go to the `{% endif %}`?

I have also tried `== true` and `sameas true`

Comment: what happens if you try to show the ` user.can_manage_techniques`  ?

Comment: If I do it as {{ user.can_manage_techniques }} Jinja2 fills it in with "False" (without the quotes)

Comment: Can't reproduce on my side...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't reproduce your problem on local with minimal app below:

```py
from flask import Flask, render_template_string
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello():
    return render_template_string('''
        {{ can }}
        {% if can %}
            {% block submenu_items %}
                <li class="pure-menu-item">New Technique</li>
            {% endblock %}
        {% endif %}
        ''', can=False)
```

IMO, the usage is correct, so you may need to check more related code.

I found why this happened after checking your code on GitHub. This issue caused by the template inheritance behavior: **In child template, contents outside the block will be skipped**.

Since your template is child template, so you need to put the if statements into the block.

Comment: Related code: I think it has something to do with the template and the block. Found a fix per my answer.

Answer (score 2):

If the `{% if %}` statement is outside the block - it is ignored. If it is inside the block, it succeeds. I know not why - but this was the fix:

```
{% block submenu_items %}
{% if user.can_manage_techniques == true %}
<li class="pure-menu-item"><a href={{ url_for('new_technique') }} class="pure-menu-link">New Technique</a></li>
{% endif %}
{% endblock %
```

Comment: Whole commit including fix is available on https://github.com/lkingsford/guitartechtree/commit/98c95269c01467c8d3abcfa0a0e0a82ae33c7737

Answer (score 0):

I believe it could be how you define `True` and `False`, in python these should be Boolean type (you can test with `type(test)`). These should not be strings or something else. The reason it always returns true could be because non emptry strings evaluate to true (e.g `Bool('false')` is `True`, while `Bool('')` is `False`).

```
from jinja2 import Template

template = Template(
    """{% if test %}
{% block submenu_items %}
My Stuff
{% endblock %}
{% endif %}
""")
```

If I run either of the below I get the expected outcome:

```
template.render(test=False)
template.render(test=True)
```

Comment: I can verify that type(state()['user'].can_manage_techniques) is a bool. I also manually added can_manage_techniques=False, and changed it to be just if can_manage_techniques (and if_can_manage_techniques == true) and in both cases, still showed the block