# Is there a way to disable API tokens for non-Sysadmins in CKAN?

Tags: ckan

Basically, I want to totally disable API access for all user other than sysadmins (v2.9.1).

1. Where in the code can I see the logic related to this? Closest I could find was via

```
$ grep -rnw /usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckan -e 'api-tokens'
/usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckan/ckan/views/user.py
/usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckan/doc/api/index.rst
/usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckan/doc/maintaining/configuration.rst
```

The ...user.py file appears to be based on Django, but not much experience w/ that framework to really know what should be changed here. Any other places to look?

2. Is there a way to create API tokens for users (eg. selected sysadmins) via the ckan CLI?

Comment: On the API front, can look into having this (https://github.com/ckan/ckan/blob/master/ckan/logic/action/create.py#L1588) part of the code first check that the user is a sysadmin (somehow, IDK ATM). Still need to look into doing something about the web browser UI API token tab.

Comment: When it comes to looking for where in the CKAN code things are (likely) happening and where you (may) want to change things, the architecture guide here is a good reference: https://docs.ckan.org/en/2.9/contributing/architecture.html?highlight=architecture

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently just hiding the API token generation tab from non sysadmin users in the web UI html (https://github.com/ckan/ckan/blob/cc000d3acf7401957d8321be53e8cabc2d9ebf3a/ckan/templates/user/api_tokens.html) by a similar mechanism that html templates can control visibility of the Visibility functionality of packages here (https://github.com/ckan/ckan/blob/master/ckan/templates/package/snippets/package_basic_fields.html#L72)...

```html
{% set user_is_sysadmin = h.check_access('sysadmin') %}
{% block page_primary_action %}
        {% if user_is_sysadmin %}

            {% if h.check_access('api_token_create', {'user': user['name']}) %}
            .
            .
            .
            {% endif %}
        {% endif %}
{% endblock page_primary_action %}
```

Note that it is *important to put the conditional inside the block tag templates* (was [not working elsewise](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55296164/8236733) and confused me for some time). This is (seems to be) due to the fact the the API tokens tab jinja2 template is an extension (child?) of the user/read_base.html template (https://github.com/ckan/ckan/blob/cc000d3acf7401957d8321be53e8cabc2d9ebf3a/ckan/templates/user/api_tokens.html#L1).

IDK if generating tokens is possible via public API. For that would need to inspect the files that seem to be related to API token creation via API:

- ckan/logic/[auth](https://docs.ckan.org/en/2.9/contributing/architecture.html?highlight=architecture#auth-functions-and-check-access)/create.py (https://github.com/ckan/ckan/blob/d43ce9bfd882f63c986711e2d59e186a58c8e489/ckan/logic/auth/create.py#L258)
- ckan/logic/[action](https://docs.ckan.org/en/2.9/contributing/architecture.html?highlight=architecture#action-functions-are-exposed-in-the-api)/create.py (https://github.com/ckan/ckan/blob/master/ckan/logic/action/create.py#L1588)

Will update post after checking these.

---

**UPDATE:**

https://github.com/ckan/ckan/blob/d43ce9bfd882f63c986711e2d59e186a58c8e489/ckan/logic/auth/create.py#L258 can be modified to something like...

```py
def api_token_create(context, data_dict):
    """
    Create new token for current user.
    """
    user = context['model'].User.get(data_dict['user'])
    return {'success': (user.name == context['user']) and (authz.is_sysadmin(user.name))}
```

...which should limit/restrict (https://docs.ckan.org/en/2.9/contributing/architecture.html?highlight=architecture#auth-functions-and-check-access) API access.

Making this change also (I'd think solely, since that seems to be the only thing the api_token_create (https://github.com/ckan/ckan/blob/d43ce9bfd882f63c986711e2d59e186a58c8e489/ckan/logic/auth/create.py#L258) is used for) hides the API token creation tab in the user's profile mgmt screen (https://github.com/ckan/ckan/blob/cc000d3acf7401957d8321be53e8cabc2d9ebf3a/ckan/templates/user/api_tokens.html#L6). (So could get rid of the code doing the conditional checks inside of the block template).

Comment: For info on how this works, see https://docs.ckan.org/en/2.9/contributing/architecture.html?highlight=architecture#logic and https://docs.ckan.org/en/2.9/contributing/architecture.html?highlight=architecture#auth-functions-and-check-access